# Normal regression function in R showing a vertical line but ggplot regression showing correlation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I'm plotting data that I have for densities of larvae that have been exposed to different treatments. I had two sampling days (4 and 7). I have been trying to do linear regression but have had some problems when plotting.

```
four <- read.csv("four.csv", header = T)

df1 <- structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "four", class = "factor"), 
    treat = c(0L, 10L, 100L, 300L), dens = c(1.2, 1.6, 1.883333333, 
    1.216666667)), .Names = c("day", "treat", "dens"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

mfour = lm(four$treat ~ four$dens)

plot(four$treat, four$dens)

abline(lm(four$treat ~ four$dens))
```

With this code I get this - a regression line which appears to show no correlation:

[image]

```
beads <- read.csv("beads.csv", header = T)

df2 <- structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        2L), .Label = c("four", "seven"), class = "factor"), treat = c(0L, 
                                                                                                       10L, 100L, 300L, 0L, 10L, 100L, 300L), dens = c(1.2, 1.6, 1.883333333, 
                                                                                                                                                       1.216666667, 1.833333333, 1.766666667, 1.4, 1.55)), .Names = c("day", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "treat", "dens"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

p1 <- ggplot(beads, aes(x=treat, y=dens, col=day)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) +
  ylab("dens") +
  xlab("treat")
p1 <- p1 + theme_few() + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Day",
                        breaks=c("four", "seven"),
                        labels=c("Four", "Seven"))
p1
```

However, when I use ggplot (as I wanted to include both of my sampling days with regression lines on the same figure) I get something that looks like correlation:

[image]

I'm quite confused as to why this is happening... has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the input data so your problem is reproducible? The regression lines you show using ggplot2 certainly make more sense than the one you show using base R graphics.

Comment: Well, you mixed up x and y in `abline(lm(four$treat ~ four$dens))`. Switch `treat` and `dens` to get the correct line. The formula is `lm(y ~ x)`, not `x ~ y`.

Comment: @LAP Probably OP confused x and y in `plot(*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
four<- structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "four", class = "factor"), 
                      treat = c(0L, 10L, 100L, 300L), dens = c(1.2, 1.6, 1.883333333, 
                                                               1.216666667)), .Names = c("day", "treat", "dens"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                      -4L))
```

You can either use lm (y ~ x)

```
plot(four$treat, four$dens)
abline(lm(four$dens~four$treat),col="green")
```

[image]

Or read coefficients from the regression model

```
mfour = lm(four$dens ~ four$treat)
abline(coef = coef(mfour), col = "blue")
```

[image]

Or use lsfit (x , y)

```
abline(lsfit(four$treat , four$dens),col="red")
plot(four$treat, four$dens)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can't believe it was that simple! Lifesaver

Comment: If you think my solution is the answer to your problem, then please accept it as answer. Thanks!